# Best Options for Mobile Data in Denmark, Germany, and the Netherlands

Tags: cellphones, internet

I will be traveling from the US to to Copenhagen, Berlin, and then Amsterdam for a total of 12 days. While there, I would like to connect to mobile data networks. I will be traveling with my Samsung S6 phone. I've looked up some options for Copenhagen (where I will land) but the roaming charges for the other countries look high. Does anyone have suggestions for an affordable option? (I'm looking for about 1GB for the whole trip).

Answer (score 1):

There are no roaming charges in the EU, as of 15/6/2017. Almost.
You can get what you want for 15 Euro.

You can buy a SIM in Copenhagen and roam with it to other EU countries, still enjoying the same terms.

Pitfalls:

1. Your data limit may be somewhat lower when roaming. You'll probably get much more than 1GB though.
2. Calls to destinations outside the EU are still subject to roaming charges, which can easily reach several Euros per minute. So use IP calls (Skype, Google Hangout, WhatsApp etc) to call home.

See [the EU "Roam Like at Home" page](http://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/consumers/telecoms-internet/mobile-roaming-costs/index_en.htm)

I didn't compare the different offers for Danmark, but a quick Google search gives [ID](https://www.idmobile.ie/prepay-your-move), who take 15 Euro for unlimited calls and 30GB data for 30 days (only 3.3GB while roaming). I'm sure you can find similar offers from other vendors.